# Generate Dynamic Array of Object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Javascript code is:

```
neighborhoods = [
  {lat: 52.511, lng: 13.447},
  {lat: 52.549, lng: 13.422},
  {lat: 52.497, lng: 13.396},
  {lat: 52.517, lng: 13.394}
];
```

I want to generate this array dynamically in java script itself. Means values are dynamic, keys are static i.e "lat", "lng". U can take it like I want to generate this array inside one loop. 
example:

```html
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
      val1=1, val2=2;
     
   //  here generate this array using above value
    val1 = val1+1; val2=val+1;

    }
```

This is just example.. I hope requirement is clear now..
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array and then put objects with properties in it like this:

```
var neighborhoods = [];
neighborhoods.push({lat: 52.511, lng: 13.447});
```

Or, if your lat, lng values are in variables so you want to build the objects dynamically, you can do this:

```
var neighborhoods = [];
var obj = {};
obj.lat = lat;
obj.lng = lng;
neighborhoods.push(obj);
```

And, if you had a source of lat, lng data that you could iterate with a `for` loop, you could just put the object creation and `.push()` into a `for` loop.

For example, if you had an array of alternating lat,lng values, you could do this:

```js
var values = [52.511, 13.447, 52.549, 13.422, 52.497, 13.396, 52.517, 13.394];
var neighborhoods = [];
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i+=2) {
    neighborhoods.push({lat: values[i], lng: values[i+1]});
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(neighborhoods));
```

Comment: if I see "neighborhoods" value on alert. it shows [object,object],[object][object].... while if I aler static neighborhoods = [ {lat: 52.511, lng: 13.447},...{..}]; this shows exact value, as it is,not [object.] why this differeence in both

Comment: @AbhishekRajawat - just run the last code snippet and it will show you the values are properly in there. `alert()` is not a valid diagnostic tool for looking at multi-level data structures in pretty much any way.  You can use `console.log()` and then look in the debug console for the actual data.  Or, you should learn the debugger where you can directly inspect the contents of any variable in scope.

Answer (score 1):

it's not entirely clear how the calculations or values need to be derived but a simple example would be:

```
var lat = 52, lng = 13;
var neighborhoods = [];

 for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
      lat += 1;
      lng += .1; 
      neighborhoods.push({lat: lat , lng : lng })
}
```

Comment: this is correct. but the problem is if i see its value on Alert(), why it shows [object,object],[object..]. Instead if I display/Alert my static "neighborhoods" it shows [ {lat:1, lng:1},{..} ] . why this d/f, I dont want object

Comment: array structures are identical . You must be altering a stringified version of the first one. Using `alert` is not a good debugging tool, use console logging methods instead

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. First of all, if you wish to use the array subscript notation, you have to pass the keys themselves (strings in your case, like this):

```
    var myAssociativeArr = [];
  for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
   var newElement = {};
newElement['id'] = val1;
newElement['lname'] = val2;
newElement['fname'] = val3;
myAssociativeArr.push(newElement);
  }
```

Where the key names are known strings, it's often preferable to use the completely equivalent notation of object properties:

```
var myAssociativeArr = [];
 for (var i=0; i <5; i++) {
var newElement = {};
newElement.id = val1;
newElement.lname = val2;
newElement.fname = val3;
myAssociativeArr.push(newElement);
 }
```